# How to match by 'undefined' value in MongoDB Aggregation Framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

How can I search for the records filtering **in** a field that has an `undefined` value:

```
db.records.aggregate({
    $match: {
        myField: "undefined",
    }
})
```

Comment: How do you define undefined ? You mean something like [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) ? If possible, add a sample document and a regular query that would return it. Looking at your question, `'undefined'` is a string, just like `'Hello, World!'`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to filter out documents that have some fields missing, use the [`$exists`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/) operator.

This works on my machine :

```
> db.test.drop()
true
> db.test.insert( {'Hello':'World!', 'myField':42})
> db.test.insert( {'Hello again':'World!'})
> db.test.aggregate({'$match':{ 'myField':{'$exists':false} }})
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("51b9cd2a6c6a334430ec0c98"),
                        "Hello again" : "World!"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

The document that has myField present does not show in the results.

Comment: The [$type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/) operator is also available to search for fields with `null` values (there's also a deprecated `undefined` type). This [FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-query-for-fields-that-have-null-values) entry explains querying for nulls and/or missing fields (the same operators are available for the aggregation framework) . For example :`db.test.aggregate({'$match':{ 'myField':{'$type':10} }})` would match documents that have a `myField` defined but its value is `null`.

Answer (score 51):

Filter it by `$type:6`, ([mongodb referece](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/), *note that this type marked as 'deprecated'*):

```
db.records.aggregate({
    $match: {
        myField: {'$type':6},
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The accepted answer doesn't seem to actually answer the question but this does and is amazingly useful give that if you try to search for `undefined` it tells you that you can't.

Answer (score 2):

If you have fields that exist but are undefined you can search for them with null.

```
db.records.aggregate({
    $match: {
        myField: {$exists: true, $eq: null},
    }
})
```