# mongodb find an unquoted keyword

Tags: mongodb

I have following records inserted into a collection. My objective is to insert a record with "Marriage" equals NULL, but it seems I made a mistake of assuming "undefined" is a keyword
and the record got inserted without double quotes(This is from mongoshell)

```
> db.userdetails.insert({"name":"jerry","age":"30","occupation":"standc"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.userdetails.find()
> db.userdetails.insert({"name":"Elaine","age":"25","occupation":"publish","married":"No"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.userdetails.insert({"name":"George","age":"30","occupation":"yankee","married":"No"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.userdetails.insert({"name":"kramer","age":"32","married":"No"})
> db.userdetails.insert({"name":"Newman", "age" : "38","occupation":"Postman","married":undefined}  )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.userdetails.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54fe04b4666af4a00dc1ef"), "name" : "jerry", "age" : "30", "occupation" : "standc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54fe83b4666af4a00dc1f0"), "name" : "Elaine", "age" : "25", "occupation" : "publish", "married" : "No" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54ff8cb4666af4a00dc1f1"), "name" : "George", "age" : "30", "occupation" : "yankee", "married" : "No" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54ffb5b4666af4a00dc1f2"), "name" : "kramer", "age" : "32", "married" : "No" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e550437b4666af4a00dc1f3"), "name" : "Newman", "age" : "38", "occupation" : "Postman", "married" : undefined }
```

Again inserted with proper quotes

```
>  db.userdetails.insert({"name":"Newman", "age" : "38","occupation":"Postman","married":"undefined"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.userdetails.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54fe04b4666af4a00dc1ef"), "name" : "jerry", "age" : "30", "occupation" : "standc" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54fe83b4666af4a00dc1f0"), "name" : "Elaine", "age" : "25", "occupation" : "publish", "married" : "No" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54ff8cb4666af4a00dc1f1"), "name" : "George", "age" : "30", "occupation" : "yankee", "married" : "No" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e54ffb5b4666af4a00dc1f2"), "name" : "kramer", "age" : "32", "married" : "No" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e550437b4666af4a00dc1f3"), "name" : "Newman", "age" : "38", "occupation" : "Postman", "married" : undefined }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e550faab4666af4a00dc1f4"), "name" : "Newman", "age" : "38", "occupation" : "Postman", "married" : "undefined" }
```

Now how to find the unquoted value for undefined 
tried below but no luck, Any help?

```
> db.userdetails.find({ "married" : /.*def.*/ })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e550faab4666af4a00dc1f4"), "name" : "Newman", "age" : "38", "occupation" : "Postman", "married" : "undefined" }

> db.userdetails.find({ "married" : undefined})
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "cannot compare to undefined",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Comment: You can search for records without a defined value for married like so: `db.userDetails.find( { married: null } )`

Comment: This didn't worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match by 'undefined' value in MongoDB Aggregation Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088045/how-to-match-by-undefined-value-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/index.html) operator

```
db.userdetails.find({"married" :{'$type':6}})
```

**OR,**

```
db.userdetails.find({"married" :{'$type':"undefined"}})
```

Here, 6 is for `undefined` , you can see it in the docs.
But, Plz note that it is ***deprecated***.

[image]

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L1q5RnhVVPl)

Comment: Both answers worked. Thank you. But the search succeeded due to the availability of type "undefined" correct? If the case is some other literal enters without double quotes what is the procedure?

Comment: You need to pass the value of that particular type

Comment: You can read more about find from here. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html